# Problem to load nanosql database data using electron in production

Tags: vue.js, electron, nano-sql

I have an anime application that I developed using vuejs + nanosql. The web version is already in production and it works very well for me.

Here the web version link: https://animefly.chrismichael.now.sh/

Now, the problem I have is to take the application to Electron. For some reason when I take the electron application to production, the data stored in the nanosql DB is not shown in the application, only the CAS are shown to me.

[image: animefly electron app]

Of course, the application in electron in local shows me the data, but in production that is where I want the data to work, they are not shown.

Repository: https://github.com/ChrisMichaelPerezSantiago/animefly*

Background.js (electron configuration): https://github.com/ChrisMichaelPerezSantiago/animefly/blob/master/src/background.js

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using the persistent method `mode: 'LS'`. For some reason there is an error with the electron when using the `mode:'PERM'`, which is a very useful method to autodetect the best method to preserve data.

```js
const nSQL = require('@nano-sql/core').nSQL;

nSQL().createDatabase({
  id: 'animeflydb',
  mode: 'LS'
  tables: [{}] //models omited for this quetion
});
```